# PHP Header Location redirect to root of current folder

Tags: php, redirect

I'm redirect from one page to the index.php file of the current directory. I'm doing so while setting a GET parameter, and I'd like to do something like the following.

`header("Location: ?v=30");`

This would be on page2.php, redirecting to index.php?v=30. I know I can fix it by using:

`header("Location: index.php?v=30");`

but I'd like to keep the URL simpler, and I was hoping there was a way to do it the former way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
header("Location: ./?v=30");
```